# Video speed control for all apps, is it possible?

Tags: video

I have a password manager that can input data no matter the app. It is phone level. I'd like there to be a way to speed up videos on apps that don't enable it.

To watch videos more quickly, I have to use this random Kiwi Browser because that's the only one I've found that allows Chrome browser extensions. For some reason, Chrome on Android doesn't allow them. Then I have to watch in Desktop mode. I do this for HBO and Hulu, but it's inconvenient, and also tonight the Hulu videos are refusing to play except on the app.

Is it possible to have a system-wide video speed override app, or like an accessibility feature? That would be great. I have the accessibility widget guy enabled in my corner because you never know when you'll want to zoom in on an app that doesn't allow it.

Anyway, does anybody know any more hacks to get more video speed?